# Unable to upload a file with RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, file-upload, data-analysis, rselenium

Using this code snippet, I have been able to get RSelenium to bring up a dialog box that allows me to select the file I would like to upload. However, my goal is to pass the file itself to the upload button; what am I missing? I am attempting to upload to a list of climate stations to https://prism.oregonstate.edu/explorer/bulk.php.

```
# Set up RSelenium -------------------------------------------------------
## load packages ----
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(netstat)
library(here)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

##Set Default download folder ----
eCaps <- list(
  chromeOptions =
    list(prefs = list(
      "profile.default_content_settings.popups" = 0L,
      "download.prompt_for_download" = FALSE,
      "download.default_directory" = gsub(pattern = '/', replacement = '\\\\', x = here("WebData")) # download.dir
    )
    )
)
default_folder = here("WebData")
## Open a chrome browser session with RSelenium ----
rs_driver_object <-rsDriver(
  browser = 'chrome',
  chromever ='108.0.5359.71',
  port = free_port(),
)

remDr <- rs_driver_object$client

##Input Locations File
LocationFile <- gsub(pattern = "/", replacement = "\\\\", x = here("InputData/prism_rr_precip_stations.csv"))

#Navigate to PRISM Explorer webpage----
remDr <- rs_driver_object$client
URL <- "https://prism.oregonstate.edu/explorer/bulk.php"
remDr$navigate(URL)

#Select Open Locations File
UploadBtn <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "upload_locations")
UploadBtn$sendKeysToElement(list(LocationFile))
UploadBtn$clickElement()
```